# Why use style.display = 'none' when loading image to canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

In the examples of [MDN's Pixel manipulation with canvas article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas), after the image is loaded they set `img.style.display = 'none';`

What is the reason to set display none?

Answer (score 0):

They want to read the pixel data from the image without displaying the `<img>` element in the page.

Comment: Only there is no `<img>` element in the example, all there is is `var img = new Image();` - and that does not display anything, as long as that image does not get added to the DOM first.

Comment: @misorude — Then its probably left over from a version of the code where it was added to the DOM.